# Recurrence and Asymptotic

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Given this recurrent relation

$$a_{n+1} \leq a_n-ka_n^2,\ k>0$$

How can I prove this asymptotic behavior not using induction?

$$a_n\leq\frac{1}{nk+a_0^{-1}}$$

I ran this numerically on MATLAB and verified it for a large number of terms.

This problem comes from the third form of entropy condition for advection equations, for my study in numerical methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Writing $b_n = ka_n$ gives $b_{n+1} = b_n(1-b_n)$ which is the logistic map https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Upper_bound_when_0_%E2%89%A4_r_%E2%89%A4_1 for $r=1$.

Comment: We need to suppose that $a_n>0$ for all $n$

Comment: @copper.hat I'll look into that!

Comment: @NN2 right! indeed in the numerical scheme, the condition where $a_n < 0$ is excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_{n} \leq a_{n-1}-ka_{n-1}^2 \iff a_n^{-1} \ge \frac{1/k}{a_{n-1}(1/k - a_{n-1)}} = a_{n-1}^{-1} + \frac{1}{1/k - a_{n-1}}$$
We deduce that
$$a_n^{-1} \ge a_{n-1}^{-1} + k \ge … \ge  a_0^{-1}+nk\tag{1}$$
From $(1)$, we will have easily your result.

Comment: beautiful. one more question, how did you come up with this approach? by chance or is there some methodology behind it?

Comment: I solve many math problems (in particular, those like this one) before. Pratice makes perfect.

Comment: Gotcha! Would you kindly refer to some books to study the relevant topics?

Comment: Perhaps you could go to the sites like [AOSP](https://artofproblemsolving.com/) (Art of Problem Solving),…

Comment: Appreciate it! You have a nice day.